# Casting a Graphics object to a subclass of Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, casting, graphics2d, classcastexception

I am in the process of creating a class which extends Graphics2D. In this class, I create some of my own methods based off of existing ones, such as a method to draw a circle centered at a point. I wish to do this so I will not have to call several different classes for rendering shapes - instead, I will only call a single, unified one.

My problem at the moment is with creating this object, which I call GraphicsEngine. In a Game thread which extends Canvas, I create a graphics object which I then attempt to cast to a GraphicsEngine object (slightly expanded below for clarity):

```
GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine;

private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bufferStrategy == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphicsEngine = (GraphicsEngine)g2d;
}
```

When I try to initialize the GraphicsEngine object, I get a ClassCastException. (

[Link to my GraphicsEngine class to prevent clutter](https://pastebin.com/m3NS1Gr9)

I am wondering why I am getting this exception, since I have not introduced any new variables - only methods, which I do not believe to matter in casting. Since Graphics can be cast to Graphics2D, I had assumed it could also be cast to a subclass of Graphics2D. I would appreciate any help in understanding why this is not the case or what error I am making in this process. Furthermore, I would appreciate any assistance in getting the initialization of the GraphicsEngine object to work.
Cheers!

Comment: Basically, you can't do what you're trying to do, because your "extended" `Graphics2D` class will never be instantiated, basically, `getDrawGraphics` is creating an instance of `Graphics2D` and pass it back to you.  A better solution would be to create a utility class which took an instance of `Graphics2D` and to which you applied what ever functionality it is your trying to implement

Comment: `Graphics` can be cast to `Graphics2D` in this instance, because the object been returned is an instance of `Graphics2D`, it will never be an instance of `GraphicsEngine`, therefore, you can't cast it as such - this is basic polymorphism

Comment: Another idea would be to use a proxy pattern, where you pass the instance of `Graphics2D` to the constructor of your `GraphicsEngine`, you would then delegate the core functionality through this instance of `Graphics2D` and you extended functionality would basically use it to perform its functionality. Personally, I prefer the utility appraoch, but that's me

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, of course! That's silly of me. Thank you for the response!